# Windows XP doesn't remember screen resolution settings

Tags: windows-xp, resolution

I bought a new Samsung to replace my old CRT. I set it to work at 1900x1600 but every time I reboot it starts at 1024x768.

The monitor is a Samsung SyncMaster P2070 and I already tried to install the drivers. How could it be solved?

In alternative there is any way to change it with a batch script in autorun?

Comment: Related [Dell Inspiron 9300 Laptop forgets External monitor (Westinghouse LCD TV) resolution setting on reboot](http://superuser.com/questions/213580/dell-inspiron-9300-laptop-forgets-external-monitor-westinghouse-lcd-tv-resoluti)