# Dell Inspiron 9300 Laptop forgets External monitor (Westinghouse LCD TV) resolution setting on reboot

Tags: windows-xp, external-display, hdtv, resolution

When I hook my laptop up to my LCD TV via the VGA cable it always starts off with a resolution of 1280x1024. I change it to my desired setting 1920x1080 and all is well until I reboot the computer and it goes back to 1280x1024.

I am using the LCD TV screen by itself, I have the laptop lid closed.

This just started to happen a few months ago, prior to that the laptop would remember the previous screen resolution setting.

Dell Inspiron 9300, running XP Pro.

Comment: I wonder if its related to an update from MS. I've recently had a similar problem with a laptop I'm using as a Media Center in the kitchen. My solution so far has been to not turn it off unless required for an update...